# Refresh Teams Bot icon + name

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I updated the name + icon of my Bot Framework Bot. In Teams I don't see a way to get it updated.. I remember having to remove some cache folders in program files manually but wonder whether there's an easier way (+ bot in Teams from Web has little to do with my local cach and also that one doesnt refresh).

How do I refresh my bot name + icon in Teams deskop + web?

Comment: Bot icon and name is cached per user. Could you please try sign out and sign in to see the new icon and name?

Comment: Hey! Tried that many times.. It is really necessary to remove quite some cache folders/items from the Teams folder.. But it is a really in-desireble way of updating name+icons to users..

Comment: Could you please share you botid? Also please check with a new user and see if the bot icon is updated.

Comment: Hey @Gousia-MSFT :)

Comment: Hey Gousia :) It does use the latest name+icons for new users.. but new users become old users :) Also, I could share a botid but it's in general for all bots I make.. Maybe you have refresh instructions? -> The exact folders to whipe and possible additional steps..

Comment: How are the new users setting up the bot? Are they installing it from the app manifest or they have searched the bot id and chat with it?

Comment: Previously through the Teams link from the Azure portal, nowadays through the app manifest. I was helped by a Microsoft engineer back in the day and he told me to remove particular local folders. I just wish there were some knowledge articles/clear instructions on this aspect. Thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, MS Teams does not provide an easy way to 'refresh' a bot icon, but it is doable. The first thing is to realize that there are two sources for the icon that come into play: 1) From your bot settings in Azure, and 2) the app manifest used for loading a custom app. (I'm not able to test installing via the Teams App store, however I would guess it would yield similar results to loading a custom app.)

In testing, each source appears to effect a different part of the Teams app. If you update your bot icon in the bot settings in Azure, this updates the conversation bot icon and the bot icon that displays when you type in a contact name. The does not update the bot's 'profile' and/or app image. These must be updated from a new manifest.

The user can uninstall and reinstall the custom loaded app (bot), however simply installing the updated manifest on top of the current bot without uninstalling *appears* to work just fine.

Lastly, in both cases, the user will need to clear out their Team's cache files. The following instructions explain how this can easily be done on a Windows 10 machine (original posting located [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f9e1c12b-47a6-4b12-8d5c-a57fda4d9042/what-folders-are-used-by-teams-for-caching)). Please forgive the formatting...markdown isn't playing nice with my letters and bullets.

```
If you want to clear MS Teams cache, you could refer to the following ways:

1.  Fully exit the Microsoft Teams desktop client. To do this, either right click Teams from the Icon Tray and select ‘Quit’, or run Task Manager and fully kill the process.
2.  Go to File Explorer, and type in %appdata%\Microsoft\teams.
3.  Once in the directory, you’ll see a few of the following folders:

 a.  From within ‘Application Cache’, go to Cache and delete any of the files in the Cache location.
    *   %appdata%\Microsoft\teams\application cache\cache

 b.  From within ‘Blob_storage’, delete any files that are located in here if any.
    *   %appdata%\Microsoft\teams\blob_storage

 c.  From within ‘Cache’, delete all files.
    *   %appdata%\Microsoft\teams\Cache

 d.  From within ‘databases’, delete all files.
    *   %appdata%\Microsoft\teams\databases

 e.  From within ‘GPUCache’, delete all files.
    *   %appdata%\Microsoft\teams\GPUcache

 f.  From within ‘IndexedDB’, delete the .db file
    *   %appdata%\Microsoft\teams\IndexedDB

 g.  From within ‘Local Storage’, delete all files.
    *   %appdata%\Microsoft\teams\Local Storage

 h.  Lastly, from within ‘tmp’, delete any file.
    *   %appdata%\Microsoft\teams\tmp

4. Once finally done clearing, you can now restart Teams from your local desktop and all cache will be cleared from the desktop app.
```

In this way, I have been able to update the bot icon. Not a terrible process, but certainly not a friendly user experience.

Hope of help!

Comment: Thanks! Really useful :)

Comment: It worked but in the "Recent" pane still the old name (with new picture).. But it's fine for now :)

Comment: @SjoerdKoolen were you able to solve the "Recent pane" issue?