# How to modify QnA follow-up prompts styling?

Tags: botframework, azure-qna-maker

In the QnA service, there's some formatting options like wrapping content inside of two asterisks to convert it to bold, or using \n\n to make a break line. It works as intended in Teams with a simple answer of the bot but it doesn't work if there's any prompts inside it.

[image: Microsoft Teams conversation with the bot]

Here's the knowledge base QnA:

[image]

I think the problem is that when there's a follow up prompt, the simple text answer converts into a hero card and for some reason it doesn't have style.

My Microsoft Teams version is 1.2.00.27559 (64-bit)

Comment: I've tested this using both Web Chat and Teams and it seems to be working just fine. Which channel are you experiencing this on?

Comment: @StevenKanberg Microsoft Teams

Comment: How were those questions added (the base and follow-up questions)? Were they imported from a file or manually entered? Also, which version of Teams are you using? Two other possible options are to try [deleting the profile](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-sdk/issues/3727#issuecomment-345379748) the bot is attached to and to try [clearing the Teams cache files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56048673/3962636).

Comment: The follow up questions were manually added just to have a simple example to show in this question, but I have more questions from a document that don't have style either. I think the problem is that when there's a follow up prompt, the simple text answer converts into a hero card and for some reason it doesn't have style. My Microsoft Teams version is 1.2.00.27559 (64-bit)

Comment: Have you tried either of the links I posted? With regards to conversion, all things being equal this shouldn't happen to you and it work just fine for me. Something else you can check (a little known trick): if you left click 10 times followed by 1 right click on the Teams icon in the system tray (not the icon in the task bar), an expansive menu will show. In there you can access the developer tools console. It's possible you may find more information being logged. Just be careful of your actions so you don't break your Teams app.

Comment: I've tried the links but didn't help in this problem (although it helped in another one I had). I tried the dev tools but I can't find anything that helps. Also, this doesn't just happen to me, other people tried it and see the same result. Maybe Microsoft has some fix for this in its roadmap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text style in a normal answer of a QnA pair uses non-html expressions like `**` for bold and `\n\n` for a breakline.

To style an answer with a follow-up prompt, it you need to use html tags like `<b><b/>` for bold and `</br>` for breakline. I'm assuming that this is beacuse the answer with a follow-up prompt is converted to a hero card and it is not compatible with non-html styling expressions.