# Bot Icon Not Updating

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I've updated the icon for my bot in the Azure portal about 35 hours ago, but it's still showing the old one for new messages sent from the bot. Surely it should have changed by now? Is there any issue with this currently?

It's correct in the Azure portal in the "Test in Web Chat", but Teams is still showing the old icon, even for new messages.

Update:

It's been a few days now, and the image finally changed, but now it's totally corrupted. Is there a way to see what's wrong with my PNG? Is there an issue with the bot framework/Teams of some sort? See images below:

Error:
[image]

Original Icon (I don't know if SO changes the file in any way, but presumably not)
[image]

Update: I've now modified my bot in the Azure portal to use the exact same icon as another bot which is working fine, and it's still broken, so I'm thinking there is an issue with the bot framework/Teams in some way at the moment.

Comment: Consider clearing your local Teams cache files following the steps described in this SO post, [Refresh Teams Bot icon + name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56048673/3962636).

Comment: Thanks Steven. I was using the browser version (this is a test tenant), but I needed to clear browser cache

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I've encountered from experience is that when updating the bot's info in "Bot App Registration" such as icon and display name.

1. You can either wait a couple days and see if it fixes itself.
2. I've consistently been able to get it to update sooner by logging in and out of Teams as well as closing it.

I have a feeling that it's related to the cache since Teams is built with Electron. Some other post mentioned this and there's no "official" surefire way to do this. Playing with the manifest also does not seem to affect it to update sooner.

TL;DR
Log in and out of Teams, close it. If using web version, clear the cache. Log back in.

Good luck!

Comment: I was using the web version (test tenant), but clearing the cache and logging out/in solved it - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling the application on Teams, sometimes it takes time.

Comment: This didn't help, unfortunately

Comment: Is your subscription valid and does the bot work properly? Also hope you added the image on the manifest package.

Comment: Yes, bot is working fine, and it's fine in the manifest, but anyway this icon, inside of chat stream, comes from Bot Framework, not from the manifest